# Uniqueness of the random variable from its distribution

Tags: measure-theory, probability-theory

> **Moderator's Note**: This question has been put on hold due to the [version over at MathOverflow](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/106335/symmetries-of-probability-distributions) having received better attention and produced an accepted answer. Interested readers are advised to visit the above link.

When talking about a single random variable, knowing only its distribution, the construction of a probability space is quite easy. Namely, let $(X,\mathscr A)$ be a measurable space and let $\mathsf Q$ be some probability measure over this space which we refer to as a distribution of some random variable. The usual definition states that there is **some** probability space $(\Omega,\mathscr F,\mathsf P)$, the random variable is
$$
  \xi:(\Omega,\mathscr F)\to(X,\mathscr A)
$$
i.e. it is a measurable map, and its distribution is a pushforward measure: 
$$
\mathsf Q:=\xi_*(\mathsf P)
$$
i.e. $\mathsf Q(A) = \mathsf P(\xi^{-1}(A))$ for any $A\in \mathscr A$.

Clearly, given $(X,\mathscr A,\mathsf Q)$ for a single random variable there is no reason to come up with a new sample space and we can take $(\Omega,\mathscr F,\mathsf P) = (X,\mathscr A,\mathsf Q)$ and $\xi:=\mathrm{id}_X$.

Let us stick to this latter case. It may happen, that there is a map 
$$
  \eta:(X,\mathscr A)\to(X,\mathscr A)
$$
such that $\eta\neq\mathrm{id}_X$ but still it holds that $\mathsf Q = \eta_*(\mathsf Q)$. I wonder if the existence of this other maps is studied somewhere.

The brief statement of the problem is thus the following: given a probability space $(X,\mathscr A,\mathsf Q)$ if the identity map $\mathrm{id}_X$ is the unique solution of the equation
$$
  \mathsf Q = \xi_*(\mathsf Q) \tag{1}
$$
where the variable $\xi$ is any measurable map from $(X,\mathscr A)$ to itself. As far as I am not mistaken, the space of solutions of $(1)$ is a monoid as it is closed under the composition of maps.

Also, if $\xi$ is a bijection which solves $(1)$ then $\xi^{-1}$ solves it as well:
$$
\xi^{-1}_*(\mathsf Q)(A) = \mathsf Q(\xi(A)) = \mathsf Q(\xi^{-1}(\xi(A))) = \mathsf Q(A).
$$

Hence, solutions of $(1)$ which are bijection form a group - which may be thought of a group of "symmetries" of $\mathsf Q$, apparently.

---

A small example just to add some clarity to the problem statement.

If $X = \{a,b\}$, $\mathscr A = 2^X$ and $\mathsf Q(a) = 0.4$ then the solution is unique. However, if $\mathsf Q(a) = 0.5$ there are exactly two solutions. Indeed, there are exactly $4$ maps $\xi:X\to X$ namely
$$
\begin{align}
  \xi^1:(a,b) \mapsto (a,a) & &\xi^2:(a,b) \mapsto (a,b)
\\
 \xi^3:(a,b) \mapsto (b,a) & &\xi^4:(a,b) \mapsto (b,b)
\end{align}
$$
In the first case, the pushforwards are 
$$
\begin{align}
  \xi^1_*(\mathsf Q) &= &(1,0) & &\xi^2_*(\mathsf Q) &= &(0.4,0.6)
\\
 \xi^3_*(\mathsf Q) &= &(0.6,0.4) & &\xi^4_*(\mathsf Q) &= &(0,1)
\end{align}
$$
and in the second case:
$$
\begin{align}
  \xi^1_*(\mathsf Q) &= &(1,0) & &\xi^2_*(\mathsf Q) &= &(0.5,0.5)
\\
 \xi^3_*(\mathsf Q) &= &(0.5,0.5) & &\xi^4_*(\mathsf Q) &= &(0,1)
\end{align}
$$
hence in the first case $(1)$ has the only solution $\xi^2$ which is of course $\mathrm{id}_X$, but in the second case both $\xi^2$ and $\xi^3$ solve the problem.

Due to this reason, I expect a non-uniqueness of the solution to reflect some kind of symmetries in the distribution $\mathsf Q$.

---

I posted the same question on [MO](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/106335/symmetries-of-probability-distributions).

Comment: In dynamical systems, given a measurable transformation of a measurable space, one is often looking for interesting probability measures which are invariant under the transformation. You're considering the converse problem, in some sense : the probability measure is given, and you're looking for transformations which leave it invariant, don't you ?

Comment: @Ahriman: exactly - this is can be considered as a sort of a dual problem to the invariant measures. Though in my case, the solution does always exist, but it can be non-unique. One can also say, that the question is a uniqueness of the representation of the distribution via the random variable over the fixed sample space.

Comment: This is known as the inverse Perron-Frobenius problem, at least when the probability is absolutely continuous w.r.t. a "natural" one. (for instance, Lebesgue measure on an interval)

Comment: @Ilya As I am trying to learn more I read your question. Didnt understand completely. In your example what is the unique solution and what are exactly two solutions? I am not knowledgeble person in this area as I said and I wanna understand the things first. If I can finally manage then I will start thinking..

Comment: @SeyhmusGüngören: sure, I've updated - please tell me if the notation is clear.

Comment: @Ilya For your last question, yes, if $\xi$ is invertible, and if it is measurable, as well as its inverse, then $\xi$ solves $(1)$ iff $\xi^{-1}$ solves it. It suffices to write it.

Comment: @Ilya I think you write the questions in a very good way. It is more related to me as I have weak knowledge. It seems that this property happens only when $P(x_i\in X)=c\forall i$?

Comment: @SeyhmusGüngören: that's nice to know, thanks! I didn't get, what does your latter expression mean, though.

Comment: @Ahriman: yeah, I've even updated it before you answered - needed to take $\xi^{-1}$ at the right place.

Comment: $(0.5,0.5)$ or $(0.2,0.2,0.2,0.2)$ if the sample space has $5$ symbols and you will have again more than one solution but iff $(0.2,0.2,0.2,0.2)$. For other cases it is again unique. Or?

Comment: @SeyhmusGüngören: or. Consider $(0.1,0.1,0.1,0.1,0.6)$. All the maps that just permute first $4$ states and leave the $5$-th on its place are solutions.

Comment: @Ilya yes you are right. Apperantly there are $N-k$ permuations with $k$ equal probabilities such that the equation that you mentioned is satisfied. Accordingly we have $(N-k)!$ such $\xi$. In such cases $\xi$ is not identity mapping. Then we still have a random variable unique to its distribution function right?

Comment: @SeyhmusGüngören: well, *by definition* we are looking for all such random variables $\xi:X\to X$ which have the same *fixed* distribution $\mathsf Q$, aren't we?

Comment: @Ilya ah ok so you mean we have a single distribution but quite many $\xi$ which are mapping to the same distribution which means that the mapping from a distribution to a random variable is not unique. From what I see it seems correct but this happens for (N-k)! special cases if there are. So what is the implication of this fact?

Comment: @SeyhmusGüngören: indeed, this is what I mean. I am not aware of any implications, but solutions of $(1)$ seems to serve as different representations of the same distribution. Moreover, *bijective* solutions of $(1)$ form something similar to a group of symmetries of a measure - but I didn't find such notion used anywhere.

Comment: @Ilya though I find it interesting. Perhaps it doesnt change anything when one uses for example not $\xi_2$ but say $\xi_3$ as the probabilities are the same at the same indexes although indexes themselves (the mapping procedure) are changing.

Comment: This question is put on-hold due to a duplicate being posted to MathOverflow, with answer accepted.

Comment: @WillieWong: hey, no problem with closing this question - but perhaps another reason rather than off-topic would be more appropriate? Also, maybe in the closing message you'd be able to put an explicit link to the MO version of the question?

Comment: @Ilya: "off-topic" is the only one that can handle "custom" reasons like the one I entered in the comments above. None of the others are better fits. And please read the moderator message that I entered _waaaay_ at the top of the question.