# Random variables with the same distributions

Tags: functional-analysis, probability-theory, banach-spaces

Let $K$ and $L$ be locally compact Hausdorff spaces. Also, let $P$ be a Radon probability measure on $K$ so that $(K,P)$ is a probability space.

I want to know, whether two random variables $X,Y\colon K\to L$ (they might be assumed to be continuous) have the same distributions.

Is it sufficient if I check that

$$\int_K f(X(\omega))P(d\omega) = \int_K f(Y(\omega))P(d\omega)$$

for each $f\in V$, where $V$ is some dense subspace of the Banach space $C_0(L)$ of continuous functions on $L$ which vanish at infinity?

Comment: you might want to see this one as well. I think Ilja has some idea about your question http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/186259/uniqueness-of-the-random-variable-from-its-distribution#comment431407_186259

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Yes.**

Recall that the distribution of $X$ is the Borel probability measure $\mu_X$ defined on $L$ via $\mu_X(A) = P(X^{-1}(A))$.  It is a standard exercise to show that for any measurable $f : L \to \mathbb{R}$, we have $\int_L f\,d\mu_X = \int_K f(X)\,dP$.  (This holds for $K,L$ any measurable spaces.)

So we want to know whether $\mu_X = \mu_Y$, and your hypothesis says that $\int f\,d\mu_X = \int f\,d\mu_Y$ for all $f \in V$.  If $\mu_X, \mu_Y$ are Radon measures on $L$, then it certainly follows from the Riesz representation theorem that $\mu_X=\mu_Y$; they are two continuous linear functionals on $C_0(L)$ which agree on a dense set.

Following [Exercise 18 in these notes of Terry Tao](http://terrytao.wordpress.com/2009/03/02/245b-notes-12-continuous-functions-on-locally-compact-hausdorff-spaces/), we can show:

> If $X$ is continuous, then $\mu_X$ is Radon.

This gives you an affirmative answer to your question.

*Proof.*  We first show $\mu_X$ is inner regular.  Let $E \subset L$ be Borel and fix $\epsilon > 0$.  $X^{-1}(E)$ is Borel, and $P$ is Radon, so there exists a compact $F \subset X^{-1}(E)$ with $P(F) > P(X^{-1}(E)) - \epsilon$.  Now $X(F)$ is a compact  subset of $E$, and we have $X^{-1}(X(F)) \supset F$.  Thus $$\mu_X(X(F)) = P(X^{-1}(X(F))) \ge P(F) > P(X^{-1}(E)) - \epsilon = \mu_X(E) - \epsilon$$ and inner regularity is proved.

As in t.b.'s comment, outer regularity follows from inner regularity by taking complements.

Note we did not use the assumption of $\sigma$-compactness which is assumed in Tao's notes, so this will work on any LCH space.

Let me also mention that other topological assumptions could make it easier.  If $L$ is [Polish](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polish_space) or even Suslin, then every Borel probability measure on $L$ is automatically Radon, and no topological assumptions on $K,X,Y$ are needed.    (This is proved, for instance, in Bogachev's *Measure Theory*.)

Comment: I'm probably overlooking something, but I think outer regularity is a consequence of inner regularity for finite measures on a locally compact Hausdorff space: If $E \subset X$ is Borel then for $\varepsilon \gt 0$ there is a compact set $K \subset X \smallsetminus E$ such that $\mu(X) - \mu(E) = \mu(E^c) \geq \mu(K) - \varepsilon$ by inner regularity, so $U = K^c \supset E$ is an open set such that $\mu(E) \leq \mu(X)-\mu(K) + \varepsilon = \mu(U) + \varepsilon$.

Comment: @t.b.: Oh, of course.  I didn't even think of using complements.  I'll edit.